# Expand a collapsible panel after pagr redirect

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Im having three panels(about us, contacts and Feedback form namely) with CollapsiblePanelExtender in a page named Home.aspx..the panels work fine in the page(showing and hiding of panels). And i have a master page which consists of three LinkButtons with the names of the panel. when i click 'about us' from any other page, im redirected to Home page..

But i also want the 'about us' panel to be expanded now.

How to make the panel expand when redirected from any other page? 
im aware of codes like

> panel1_CollapsiblePanelExtender.collapsed = true:

what im currently doing is, since the links are in master page, i create querystring like

> Response.Redirect("Home.aspx?pg=1")

for 'about us' and 2 and 3 for contacts and Feedback panels respectively.
And in Page_Load() of Home.aspx, i check the value in querystring and then i set 
this

> Panel1_CollapsiblePanelExtender.Collapsed = false;

for About Us and respectively.. but when im redirected first time to this page, the panel does no expand. but when i click the link again, the respective panel expands.
What am i missing here. And also would like to know about

> Panle1_CollapsiblePanelExtender_ClientState